# Адаптивная верстка

Tags: jquery, html, вёрстка, javascript

Друзья, скажите, а как делается адаптивная верстка? Надо очень долго верстать под все разрешения или же есть специальные инструменты, которые все тянут? Хочется выслушать не ответ в лоб, а рассуждения как это делают люди и руками.

Comment: А при попытке открыть адрес http://google.com браузер говорит что - **Невозможно найти удалённый сервер**? Первая ссылка из запроса адаптивная верстка такая - [Адаптивная верстка в примерах][1]


З.Ы. Топик нужно было назвать - Погуглите за меня по запросу [адаптивная верстка][2]


  [1]: http://alpatriott.ru/articles/адаптивная-верстка-в-примерах/
  [2]: https://www.google.com.ua/search?rls=ru&q=%D0%90%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest

Comment: да нет, я просто хотел узнать как люди делают, а не что пишут.

Comment: делают так же как и пишут.. так же как и пишут как и говорят)))))

Comment: Внутри компании, для верстки сайтов мы используем фрейм bootstrap. Естественно на фреймверке все не заканчивается, стили пишем на sass. Удобно, быстро, качественно.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите как это сделано в [`bootstrap`](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive).

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox решает большенство задач по адаптивной верстке

Answer (score 0):

Вот сайт на русском, по [Bootstrap](http://bootstrap.veliovgroup.com/).

Надеюсь поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно часто используют готовые фреймворки, такие как: http://getbootstrap.com/ , http://foundation.zurb.com/ .

Но на профессиональном уровне, люди верстают сетку вручную. При этом используют не чистый css, а препроцессоры SASS и LESS. Вот неплохой урок, по созданию базовой сетки на SASS http://callmenick.com/post/maintainable-responsive-web-design-with-sass .

Однако, в 2016 году существуют более современные инструменты такие как postCSS. На которых адаптивная сетка создается за 1 минуту, смотрите на youtube PostCSS.